# how can i access ids in kivy screenmanger

Tags: python

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class ScreenHome(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenNew(Screen):
    pass


class Performer(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ScreenHome(name="home"))
        sm.add_widget(ScreenNew(name="new"))
        return sm

    def test(self):
        text = self.root.get_screen('<ScreenNew>').mytext
        label = self.root.get_screen('<ScreenNew>').mylabel
        label.text = text.text
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Performer().run()
```

kv file

```
<ScreenHome>:
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        on_press: app.root.current = 'new'
<ScreenNew>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        Label:
            id: mylabel

        TextInput:
            id: mytext
        Button:
            on_press: app.test()
            text: "adauga"
            font_size: 50
        Button:
            text: 'Home'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'home'
```